# BATCH Check if a txt file contains a string and execute the batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, text-files

I would like to I would like to continue running the batch only if a specific string exists in a txt file.

Example:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if....
Findstr "check_ok" "C:\tmp\test.txt"
( 
     ...continue...
) ELSE (
exit
)
```

but I don't want to create a file.

I can't find the correct way to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what you're asking, because you're already running the batch file so how do you not run the batch file to find out if you should run the batch file?

Regardless, I'm going to see if this helps you:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Check for "check_ok" and exit the batch file if it is NOT found
Findstr -m /S /C:"check_ok" "C:\tmp\test.txt" || goto :eof

:: If we get here, then check_ok was found
:: Continue with the rest of your batch file
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!

sorry for the description of the problem, I edited the request.
is it better now?

Comment: Yes, the question is better.  I believe my answer will help you.

Comment: As a side note, to the above, I'd just like to add that `check_ok` does not contain any metacharacters, so there's no need to use the `/C` option. I would suggest we determine the actual intent and adjust the options accordingly, for instance, `FindStr "\<check_ok\>" "C:\tmp\test.txt">NUL||GoTo :EOF` would be more specific, as may `FindStr /L "check_ok" "C:\tmp\test.txt">NUL||GoTo :EOF`. You could even use `Find.exe` instead, `Find "check_ok"<"C:\tmp\test.txt">NUL||GoTo :EOF` or `Find " check_ok "<"C:\tmp\test.txt">NUL||GoTo :EOF`